# Problems in the for loop in language C

Tags: c, for-loop

The program compiles perfectly, the problem is the cycle, it does not show me the position

here goes the include of library stdio.h

```
int main(void)
{ int x, i=0,j=0, a[100];
  char sal;

    printf("Este programa lee un arreglo de numeros enteros y un numero x, y muestra en pantalla los indices de las posiciones en donde se encuentra ese numero x\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
        i++;
        printf("Si desea salir presione s: ");
        scanf(" %c", &sal);
    }while(sal!='s');   

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la variable x: ");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    for (j; j<=i; j++)
    {
        if(a[i]==x) 
            printf("%i",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It did not work

Comment: It should be `for(j; j< i; ++j)` because `i` is the value of the last input plus one. And in the loop it should be `if(a[j] == x) printf("%i ", j)`. Use `j`, the running index, not `i`.

Comment: regarding: `for (j; j<=i; j++)`  The first parameter `j;`   results in the following output from the compiler: "untitled1.c:18:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value"  Suggest using: `for( ; j<=i; j++ )`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions:  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In all the calls to `scanf()`, in the posted code, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: when posting a question about a runtime problem, as this code is doing, Post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.. That includes the `#include` statements as making us guess as to which header files you actually included can/will result in the question being ignored

Comment: BTW:  regarding: `here goes the include of library stdio.h`   `stdio.h` is a header file, not a library (although many header files have the same base name as the associated header file)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) insert appropriate single space inside parens, after semicolons, after commas, around C operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You condition of the `for` loop should be `j<i`, not `j<i+1`. When the `while`
loop exits, `i` has the value for the next input, but it has not been set because
the loop exited.

Also you are using the index `i` instead of `j` in the `for`-loop. `j` is the
running index, not `i`:

```
for (j; j<i; j++)
{
    if(a[j]==x) 
        printf("%i", j);
}
```

would be correct.

Your `while` loop is ok, but a bit clunky. First you don't check if you are
writing past the limit of `a`. The conditions should be

```
while(sal!='s' && i < (sizeof a / sizeof *a));
```

so that the user cannot input more values than `a` can hold.

The way you exit the loop is also awkward, the user has to type something
different to `s` to continue **and** it can only be **one** character. This would be
better:

```
int c;
char line[100] = { 0 };
do
{
    printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &a[i]);
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // to clear the input buffer
    i++;

    printf("Si desea salir ingrese SALIR. Para continuar presione ENTER: ");
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

} while(strcmp(line, "SALIR\n") && strcmp(line, "salir\n") && i < (sizeof a / sizeof *a));
```

Note that `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings are equal, a non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A tip, you should always set the loop counter to 0 either right before the loop, or in the loop. And it's always a good practice to initialize all variables during declarations. In your case, you did not initialize integer array. Below is a modified version of your code.

```
int main(void)
{
    int x, i, j;
    x = i = j = 0;

    int a[100] = { 0 };

    char sal = 0;

    printf ("Este programa lee un arreglo de numeros enteros y un numero x, "
            "y muestra en pantalla los indices de las posiciones en donde se "
            "encuentra ese numero x\n");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

        i++;

        printf("Si desea salir presione s: ");
        scanf(" %c", &sal);

        if (sal == 's')
            break;

    }

    printf("Ingrese el valor de la variable x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == x)
            printf("%d", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: `%d` and `%i` are perfectly equivalent in `printf`; they are both valid in `scanf` as well, but there `%d` accepts only decimal values, while `%i` accepts octal and hexadecimal values as well.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for information. I have been working in C for past few months, but did not know about %i. Thanks for enlightening me. :)

Comment: You could handle both `'s'` and `'S'` for exit with `if (sal == 's' || sal == 's' - 'a' + 'A')`

Comment: Just another note: always, always check the return of `scanf`, e.g. `if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` With `" %c"` you will need to check if not `EOF` to protect against the user pressing `Ctrl+d` (or `Ctrl+z` on windoze) to generate a manual `EOF` to cancel input.

Comment: Hey David, that is a great suggestion. Error handling is crucial in world of software. Always check return value of methods and handle situations accordingly.